# Exact Target upsertDE to more than one Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I currently have a landing page which I'm writing the data to a Data Extension is it possible to write the same data for two different data extension at the same time?

currently i am using upsertDE Ampscript and cant get it to write to the second Data Extension

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only option is to run multiple upsertDE functions in your AMPscript block.

For example:

```
%%[

SET @DE1 = "dataextension_1"
SET @DE2 = "dataextension_2"

SET @attr1 = RequestParamater(attr1)
SET @attr2 = RequestParamater(attr2)

IF NOT EMPTY(attr1) AND NOT EMPTY(@attr2) THEN
upsertDE(@DE1, 1, "attr1",@attr1,"attr2",@attr2)
upsertDE(@DE2, 1, "attr1",@attr1,"attr2",@attr2)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks for that. is there a way to add entries and not add or update? the reason is to i can keep an audit trail of all the submissions.

Comment: yes - use the InsertData or InsertDE function instead. This will only add the information. If it currently exists on the Data Extension, it will not change it. https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - The solution I found was to put your Upsert/Insert/Update queries in two different blocks, so rather than

```
%%[

UpsertDE(query1)

UpsertDe(query2)

]%%
```

I did:

```
%%[

UpsertDE(query1)

]%%

%%[

UpsertDE(query2)

]%%
```

And this worked fine.